# Generator direct drive of AC \ Heat Pump

Tags: generator

What are the key considerations in selecting a generator \ Heat:AC system direct drive system?  The application would be for a home in Florida, so in all likeliness cooling used in a lengthy power failure.

Are fuels such as kerosene or LPG preferable over gasoline in a sustained (1-week) natural disaster (hurricane)?

Comment: A key consideration here is installation of the proper legal and up to code transfer switch.

Comment: On top of the transfer switch your peak load on your electrical system so you get a system that is large enough.